# Using a LinkedBlockingQueue and flush to mysql

Tags: java, concurrency

Would a linkedblockingqueue be suitable for the following:

```
1. insert strings (maximum 1024 bytes) into the queue at a very high rate
2. every x inserts or based on a timed interval, flush items into mysql
```

During the flush, I was looking at the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

At was wondering it drainTo would be a good choice, since I have to aggregate before flushing.

So I would drainTo the items in the queue, then iterate and aggreate and then write to mysql.

Will this be suitable for upto 10K writers per second?

Do I need to consider any locking/synchronization issues or is that taken care of already?

**I will store this linkedblockingqueue as the value in a concurrenthashmap.**

Items will never be removed from the hashmap, only inserted if not present, and if present, I will append to the queue.

Comment: Why do you have the `ConcurrentHashMap` there?  What are the keys in the map?

Comment: Is there 1 or many MySQL inserter thread inserters?  1 per queue or 1 total?

Comment: @Gray the keys will be a clientID, and for writing I can make it easier and just have a single thread to flush.

Comment: It may be easier to have a thread per queue.  Feel free to add comments to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every queue you need a thread and a connection, so I wouldn't create too many queues.  You can perform over 10K writes per second provided your MySQL server can handle this (you will only know when you test it) LinkedBlockingQueue is thread safe, and provide you have all your queues created before you start you don't need any locking/synchronization.

If you are inserting long Strings up to 1024 characters at 10 K per second you are likely to run out of memory pretty fast. (up to 36 GB per hour) Instead I would have the database only insert new strings.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit if the inserter is per queue or for all queues.  If I am understanding your spec, I would think something like the following would work.

Writer adds an item to the one of the `LinkedBlockingQueue` collections in your map.  If the size of the queue is more than X (if you want it per queue) then it signals the MySQL inserter thread.  Something like this should work:

```
queue.add(newItem);
// race conditions here that may cause multiple signals but that's ok
if (queue.size() > 1000) {
    // this will work if there is 1 inserter per queue
    synchronized (queue) {
        queue.notify();
    }
}
...
```

Then the inserter is waiting on the queue and in something like the following loop:

```
List insertList = new ArrayList();
while (!done) {
    synchronized (queue) {
        // typically this would be while but if we are notified or timeout we insert
        if (queue.size() < 1000) {
            queue.wait(MILLIS_TIME_INTERVAL);
        }
    }
    queue.drainTo(insertList);
    // insert them into the db
    insertList.clear();
}
```

It gets a bit more complicated if there 1 one thread doing the inserts across all queues.  I guess the question is then why do you have the `ConcurrentHashMap` at all?  If you do have 1 inserter which, for example, is inserting into multiple tables or something then you will need a mechanism to inform the insert *which* queue(s) need to be drained.  It could just run through all of the queues in the map but that might be expensive.  You would synchronize on some global lock object or maybe the map object instead of the queue.

Oh, and as @Peter Lawrey mentioned, you will quickly run out of memory if your database is slower than the writers so make sure the queues have a proper capacity set so they limit the writers and keep the working memory down.

Hope this helps.